# How to get around rept() 32000 max char limit?

Tags: google-sheets

Helllo,
I am trying to have the formula below repeat the cells in B2:J2 and add 2452 at the end of each cell. However, I am hitting a character limit with the rept() function. I've tried a number of different methods, but I think I am missing something.

```
=arrayformula({split(transpose(SPLIT(rept(join("\",B2:J2&".2452")&"\",690),"\")),".")})
```

The formula works if i lower the 690 repetitions to something under 590. However, the way my data is presented I need it at 690.

Example page:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1swdWQcO3bI3fO0lXLh2W1NBlzjVOUKrA1HVokCAmzd8/edit#gid=0

Comment: This feels like an xyproblem.  http://xyproblem.info/  If you have data a certain way, and are trying to reorganize it, I might be able to help, but would need to see a sample of the raw, and a sample of how you'd like it to look in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this works?

```
= ArrayFormula(split("Week " &mod(row(A1:A6210)-1, 9)+1&"_2452", "_"))
```